# Why is (!!document.documentMode == true ) not the same (document.documentMode == false )?

Tags: javascript

This really confuses me.  I'm checking for an IE 10+ browser and everything online says use  `(!!document.documentMode == true )`, but why not `(document.documentMode == false )`?  How are they not the same?  Are we saying in the first the `document.documentMode` is missing and not false but null?

Comment: `!` reverses the boolean sense, while `!!` basically is `Boolean(something)`. They're opposites.

Comment: The `!!` forces the value to be a boolean without negating it. It's a double negative. One `!` casts the value to a boolean in order to negate it, and the second `!` negates it again, giving you the original value cast to a boolean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

`!` forces the value to convert to that opposite truthy boolean. `!!` does that twice, meaning it forces it to convert to the same truthy boolean.

```
false => false
!false => true
!!false => false
```

Therefor

```
!!<Falsy value> => false
!!<Falsy value> == true => false
```

Comment: You can use `Boolean(<value>)` to convert to a bool!

Comment: Yes, IMO that is the better way to do it, but `!!` is trendy right now

Answer (score 0):

Because `undefined` is not equal than `false`.

However, if you use `Boolean` in your `document.documentMode` it will evaluate it to true

`Boolean(document.documentMode) == false`

Because `undefined` is a falsy value

more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).